# Add info from .dat to .csv file

Tags: text-processing, awk, grep, scripting

I have a text file like this:

```
sn,device_id,ip_address
 P7K08UQ         , BIOTERIO, 148.111.83.177
 H006K022        , N7K-LAN(JAF1651ANDL), 148.111.4.111
 FNS174002FT     , LAB_PESADO, 148.111.131.188
 FNS14420533     , Arquitectura_Salones, 148.111.135.44
 H006K021        , CIVIL_253, 148.111.132.666
 H006K083        , Arquitectura, 148.111.134.111
 H006K032        , ING_CIVIL, 148.111.133.777
 FNS16361SG0     , ING_CIVIL_DIR, 148.111.4.188
 H006K040        , Ingenieria_Posgrado, 148.111.137.253
 00000MTC1444080Z, Biblio_Barragan, 148.111.136.61
 FNS11190FLE     , Electronica_Edif_3, 148.111.130.253
```

And another one like this:

```
SN: FDO1129Z9ZJ
Barragan_3750
IP address: 148.111.4.122
```

I would like to add the second file's info into the first one using `awk` like this:

```
sn,device_id,ip_address
     P7K08UQ         , BIOTERIO, 148.111.83.177
     H006K022        , N7K-LAN(JAF1651ANDL), 148.111.4.111
     FNS174002FT     , LAB_PESADO, 148.111.131.188
     FNS14420533     , Arquitectura_Salones, 148.111.135.44
     H006K021        , CIVIL_253, 148.111.132.666
     H006K083        , Arquitectura, 148.111.134.111
     H006K032        , ING_CIVIL, 148.111.133.777
     FNS16361SG0     , ING_CIVIL_DIR, 148.111.4.188
     H006K040        , Ingenieria_Posgrado, 148.111.137.253
     00000MTC1444080Z, Biblio_Barragan, 148.111.136.61
     FNS11190FLE     , Electronica_Edif_3, 148.111.130.253
     FDO1129Z9ZJ     , Barragan_3750, 148.111.4.122
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The main job is to combine the three lines in the "second" file into a single line. Assuming that the  file format will be the one that you have given in the example, the following awk would do that trick

```
awk '{ printf "%s", $NF; if (NR % 3 == 0) print ""; else printf "," }' second_file
```

Now the second part is adding to file1, that could be accomplished by a simple redirection `>>`

The complete command then would be

```
 awk '{ printf "%s", $NF; if (NR % 3 == 0) print ""; else printf "," }' second_file >> first_file
```